# In the context of OpenCV, what is `ippicv`?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.1

While building OpenCV 3.1.0 on CentOS I've been getting a hash mismatch error caused by a file called `ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz`. After some research I have found that the two prevailing solutions suggested by several people (for example [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5973)) are the following.

1. Build again with option `-DWITH_IPP=OFF`.
2. Manually download the file `ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz` and put it in the right place.

Now solution 2 above didn't work for me, and I feel a bit nervous about solution 1. My fear is that building OpenCV with `-DWITH_IPP=OFF` might prevent some things from working properly later, thus making a time bomb. My question is what is IPP? Or `ippicv`? Or ICV? I'm not even sure what to ask here. I want to know what I'm about to disable in the build before I disable it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Intel IPP software building blocks are highly optimized instruction sets (using Intel AVX, AVX2 and SSE).It offers a special subset of functions for image processing and computer vision called the IPP-ICV libraries. More information can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-open-source-computer-vision-library-opencv-faq/). Also [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Opencv3) you can find some information about speedup.

If real-time processing is not critical in your project or its performance is enough you can safely disable it.

Comment: You won't find it by looking at: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/ - it has to be: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/tree/ippicv/master_20151201/ippicv (as of today)

Comment: Tried to build opencv4 on Win11 (on Parallels on Mac M1) and it seems build of opencv world failed due to missing ippicv. And downloading from the link you provided I see there are two folders ia32/intel64, so I guess it's not supposed to work on new M series Macs ?